# How to extract substring from string with two possible formats using regex?

Tags: regex, regex-group

Using Regex, how do I extract the substring `ACB-R5TGDRSAuE76Tt1ZPa5qPv9cp23QLaJfni84B7MXrcI` from a string which can have either of these (url) formats:

1. `https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/ACB-R5TGDRSAuE76Tt1ZPa5qPv9cp23QLaJfni84B7MXrcI=s120-c-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo-br100`
2. `https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/ACB-R5TGDRSAuE76Tt1ZPa5qPv9cp23QLaJfni84B7MXrcI=s120-c-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo-br100`

- The difference is in the `/a/`, `/a-/` prefixes.

I am unable to make the correct regex expression myself. The furthest I've gotten to is this: `(?<=/a/)(.*?)=` but that doesn't solve it.

Comment: java != javascript. remove unrelated tags

Answer (score 1):

1. To match the prefix but ignore it in the result, you're using the lookbehind expression (`?<=`) correctly but you just need to tell it to match either `/a/` or `/a-/` with the `|` operator. Also it's smart to escape special characters such as `/` and `-`, so you need to add `\` before them to tell Regex that you want them to be treated as normal characters. So the correct prefix match expression is: `(?<=\/a\/|a\-\/)`
2. You don't need the `?` inside `(.*?)` since you know there is supposed to be some characters in the ID. Just use `(.*)`
3. To match the suffix (`=`) but ignore it in the result, you need to use the lookahead expression (`?=`): `(?=\=)`

The final regex expression `(?<=\/a\/|a\-\/)(.*)(?=\=)` will give you the substring you're looking for.